# Android FragmentScenario - Unable to find package androidx.fragment.app.testing

Tags: android, android-junit, android-fragmentscenario

I'm getting this error while trying to use FragmentScenario in Android

```
error: package androidx.fragment.app.testing does not exist
import androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario;
                                    ^
```

This is my simple Unit test example:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario;
import android.os.Build;

import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4;

import org.junit.Ignore;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.robolectric.annotation.Config;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@Config(manifest = Config.NONE, sdk = Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
public class MainActivityTest {
    @Test
    public void testFragmentScenario() {
        FragmentScenario<BlankFragment> scenario = FragmentScenario.launchInContainer(BlankFragment.class);
    }
}
```

build.gradle(app):

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    def test_version = '1.2.0'
    def fragment_version = '1.2.4'
    debugImplementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:$fragment_version"
    testImplementation "androidx.test:core:$test_version"
    testImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    testImplementation "androidx.test:runner:$test_version"
    testImplementation "androidx.test:rules:$test_version"
    testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.3'
}
```

What am I missing because a few months ago this piece of code works.

Comment: did you ever resolve this?

Comment: For what it's worth, my dependencies are near identical to yours and the `androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario` import resolves for me. You might just need to resync your project with the Gradle files?

Comment: Hi @StealthRabbi sorry for the late reply. I haven't tried it since and moved on to other things. Let me try it soon and update here.

Answer (score 2):

Check your build variants in Android Studio. It should be debug

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you use the wrong way, try to change `debugImplementation` to `testImplementation` in `build.gradle`. Hope it will helpful to you.

Comment: This is not possible. androidx.fragment:fragment-testing only allows debugImplementation